# Cannot see all javascript log messages

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I am working on a web application. The file tree is something like :
`inetpub/wwwroot/app-name/assets/js/lib/some-library`. Some-library represents many different libraries like jquery, query-string.
Here, app-name folder contains `index.html`, js folder contains the main js scripts while some-library contains the js scripts of that library.

I have some `console.log()` statements in the main js files as well as in library js files (let us say that I edited the library script as well). If I run index.html via a double-click, I can see all the logs in my Chrome console. However, if I run the app using localhost (IIS) I can only see the log messages of the main js files. Also, the kind of error that I am facing in both cases is different.

Is there something I can do to see the log messages of the library js files (deeper in the file-tree) on the console when running the app via localhost?

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that the browser is removing all the edits that I made to those files (this means all the `console.log()` statements). Or more appropriately, The script that the web browser is showing is just as it was before I made edits. Is it possible that the web browser is fetching those files not from the directory I placed it in but from some other location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is a lot simpler than what you are thinking. When accessing a website (even via localhost) the browser will cache asset files associated with that URL to reduce bandwidth on subsequent requests. I'm guessing when you open the file in browser it always reloads the asset files as its a local path and not a URL.

Try an "Empty cache and hard reload" if you are using chrome (Open dev tools and click and hold on the refresh button till you see the drop down). That should force reload your asset files.